# Communicating with MongoDB from TypeScript using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

As far as I understand , one have to use async callbacks for all IO in NodeJS (?)

I'm trying to wrap my head around [this example code](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples%2fimageboard%2fdb.ts) provied by Microsoft.

They start with a db.open(function() {});
That is, no code is provided in the callback of "open"..

So all code that interacts with the db object will execute before open has completed.
How can their sample work?

For me in my own code to be able to write any data to the DB I have to provide the writing code as a callback to the db.open function.

another weird problem when running my code, after the data is written, the nodejs server doesnt exit even though all user code have completed.
Why is that?